# Found many regex but trying them in my javascript fails

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this bit of code for shopping cart, but it fails if there is a decimal value (cents). I tried substituting the regex, but then it returns a `NaN` (Not a Number) error:

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var $selects = $("select").change(function (e) {
    var total = 0;
    $selects.each(function() {

        var val = this.value.match(/^\$(\d+)$/);
        total += val ? +val[1] : 0;
    });
    $("#total").val(total);
});
});
</script>
```

Regex substituted in the match line:

```
var val = this.value.match(/^\$(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2}\)?$/);
```

Comment: You can try regex statements for JS on: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Well your regular expression only looks for whole numbers. A `.` is not a number. And you are adding strings, not numbers.

Comment: `/^\$(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2}\)?$/` is a syntax error: `SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical`

Comment: Why are you even regexp matching your own code? Put a span or something around the value and just fetch it. Or store the entire cart in javascript at all times and update your values from there. This seems wrong.

Comment: 2 starting "(" and zero ")" in this regexp. +1 ")" character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you simply want to match a number with a decimal value or no decimal value.  You can use this:

```
^\$([\d\.]+)$
```

[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/wB4nD1/1)

If you want to limit the decimal to two places, throw it in a uncaptured group and use the `{}` operator:

```
^\$(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

1. `^`: Start of string / line.
2. `\$`: Match `$` literally.
3. `(`: Start capture group.
4. `\d+`: Match one or more of a digit
5. `(?:`: Start a group that doesn't capture.
6. `\.`: Match `.` literally.
7. `\d{1,2}`: Match a digit with a length of 1 or 2.
8. `?`: Lazy selector, the whole decimal scenario is optional (so you can match whole numbers).
9. `$`: Match end of string / line.

Comment: First one would be fine when you can trust the data, but it would fail with `"1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.......1.........."`

Comment: @epascarello, Good point, in that case you can do: `^\$([\d]+\.[\d]+)$`

Comment: You need not put one shorthand class (`\d`) to a character class.

Answer (score 2):

To match strings like `$123.56` or `$12.5`, you may use this fixed regex:

```
^\$(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
                   ^ ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZ4cZ9/2)

It will also match integer values because of the `?` quantifier after the non-capturing group `(?:\.\d{1,2})`.

**Note**:  it is practically your same regex, where I removed the backslash before the last `)`, and added a `)` at the end of the pattern to close the first and only capturing group properly.

Comment: I did not write the explanation of the regex because it is your regex with 2 modificatons: I removed the backslash before the last `)`, and added a `)` at the end of the pattern to close the first and only capturing group properly.

Comment: I thought  your intention was to only match 1 or 2 decimals,  or integers, I see I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var val = this.value.match(/^\$(\d+\.?\d*)$/);
```